# Function returns undefined when it should return a boolean result

Tags: javascript

I am trying to have `checkNull1` return true but it returns undefined. My understanding is that `checkNull2` should work exactly the same way as `checkNull1` but instead uses a variable to store the return result. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

```
function checkNull1(obj) {
    return
    (obj.a === null &&
    obj.b === null &&
    obj.c === null)
  ;
}

function checkNull2(obj) {
    var isNull =
    (obj.a === null &&
    obj.b === null &&
    obj.c === null)
  ;

  return isNull;
}

function checkNull3() {
  var nullObj = null;
  return nullObj === null;
}

var object1 = {};
object1.a = null;
object1.b = null;
object1.c = null;

console.log("checkNull1: " + checkNull1(object1));
console.log("checkNull2: " + checkNull2(object1));
console.log("checkNull3: " + checkNull3());
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ravvy/ah8hn2qy/

Comment: The problem is [automatic semicolon insertion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting caught in a lexing/parsing "quirk".

In JavaScript there is something called [Automatic Semicolon Insertion](http://www.2ality.com/2011/05/semicolon-insertion.html) or ASI for short. Basically what this means is that the JavaScript engine will try and fix your some parts code for you by inserting a `;` for you, terminating statements where it can.
Statements like `return`, `break`, `throw` and `continue` will always have a semi-colon inserted when a trailing newline is found by the parser.

Your function is getting caught in this. What the engine really does is this:

```
function checkNull1(obj) {
    return;
    // Code below will not be used. it's dead.
}
```

So the fix would be to move the condition up on to the same line as `return` and more long term fix, even though in this example is not in violation of this, but to remember to always end statements with a semi-colon even though it sometimes is optional.

```
function checkNull1(obj) {
    return (obj.a === null &&
       obj.b === null &&
       obj.c === null); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation caused the wrong behavior. Something like this would work:

```
function checkNull1(obj) {
    return (obj.a === null &&
    obj.b === null &&
    obj.c === null);
}
```

Be careful with semicolons in Javascript: http://es5.github.io/#x7.9